# Bound on the $2$-norm of a diagonal sub-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be an *invertible* real matrix and write $A_d$ for the sub-matrix consisting of its diagonal part only, namely $(A_d)_{ij} = A_{ij}$ if $i = j$ and $0$ otherwise. I can prove that
$$\lVert A_d \rVert_2 \leq \lVert A_d \rVert_F \leq \lVert A \rVert_F \leq \sqrt{n}\lVert A \rVert_2 $$
but can this inequality be improved? In other words, can we find $A$ invertible such that $\lVert A_d \rVert_2 = \sqrt{n}\lVert A \rVert_2$?

Comment: *"I can prove that $\lVert A_d \rVert_2 \leq \sqrt{n}\lVert A \rVert_2$ by using inequalities with the Frobenius norm"*. What is the norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ in your question? The standard notation for Frobenius norm is $\|\cdot\|_F$, while $\|\cdot\|_2$ conventionally denotes the *induced* $2$-norm (i.e. the largest singular value).

Comment: Yes, $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ is the $2$-norm, but proving the inequality goes through the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|a_{ii}|$ be the diagonal entry of $A$ with the largest magnitude and let $e_i$ be the $i$-th vector in the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then
$$
\|A_d\|_2=|a_{ii}|\le\|Ae_i\|_2\le\max_{\|u\|_2=1}\|Au\|_2=\|A\|_2.
$$
Clearly this inequality is tight when $A$ is a diagonal matrix. It also implies that $\|A_d\|_2=\sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$ only if $\sqrt{n}\|A\|_2\le\|A\|_2$. Therefore, provided that $n\ge1$, $\|A_d\|_2$ can possibly be equal to $\sqrt{n}\|A\|_2$ only when $n=1$ or $A=0$.

Comment: Wonderful, so you have proved that $\lVert A_d \rVert_2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_2$, which is clearly the best bound. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed comment. Is it possible to explain why $\| Ae_i\|_2 \geq |a_{ii}|$? Any comment is highly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry I have another question. How do we know that $a_{ii}$ has the maximum absolute value and not $a_{ji}$ with $j\neq i$?  I mean someone could also  write $\| Ae_i\|_2 \geq |a_{ji}|$ for some $j \neq i$. Could you please explain?

Comment: @darkmoor $\|Ae_i\|_2$ is indeed $\ge |a_{ji}|$, but we need $|a_{ii}|$ rather than $|a_{ji}|$ to establish the inequality $\|A_d\|_2\le\|Ae_i\|_2$ because both $A_d$ and $Ae_i$ contains the element $a_{ii}$.

Comment: @user1551 thanks.  As you mentioned we choose $a_{ii}$ so as to connect $A_d$ with $Ae_i$ but how do we know that $|a_{ii}|$ is the diagonal entry of $A$  with the largest magnitude when choosing it in order to connect $|a_{ii}|$ with $\| A_d\|$?

Comment: @darkmoor Strange question. Since $\|A_d\|=\max_{1\le i\le n}|a_{ii}$, we of course would like to consider $|a_{ii}|$.

Comment: I think I see it now. We use $\| A\|_2 \geq | a_{ii}|$ and that apply $\max_i$ on both side to get $\| A\|_2 \geq \max_i | a_{ii}|$?

Comment: @darkmoor That's one way to think about it.

Comment: @Thoth No. The inequality $\|A_d\|_2\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|A\|_2$ is false in general. Consider $A=I_2$ for instance.

Comment: @Thoth I don’t understand your question. Since $\|A_d\|_2\le\|A\|_2$, if the RHS is $\le L$, of course the LHS is also $\le L$, because the relation $\le$ is transitive.

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted the last two comments I made as it was noise. I am looking at $\| Ae_i\|_2 \geq |a_{ii}|$ which as far I understand is $\| Ae_i\|_2 \geq \max_i |a_{ii}|$. How do we end up arithmetically in this lower bound that has an absolute value? Can you please explain or make an edit? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I have started with $\max_{\|x\|_2=1} \sqrt{x^TA^TAx} \geq \sqrt{e_j^TA^TAe_j}=\sqrt{ \sum_k a_{kj}^2}$. Can we just say that $\sqrt{ \sum_k a_{kj}^2} \geq \sqrt{ a_{jj}^2} = |a_{jj}|$? It seems to me that we loose a lot of information and the inequality losses its tightness. If I understand correct the term tight inequality. Can you please comment?

Comment: I think I got it combining the result in [\[1\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082880/are-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-and-just-its-diagonal-related/3094611#comment10236859_3094611).